# Trying to transfer money from a Bank to Paypal account. Being asked for a valid Swift Code

Tags: banking, paypal

I gave a bank my Paypal account number, IBAN and other details to send some amount to my Paypal account, and I got a response saying that I have an invalid `SWIFT CODE` and the transaction failed without success.

Prior to that, I used to believe, it was enough for a bank to have an IBAN number to send money anywhere, but that does not seem to be the case.

So, what can I do to receive money from say, ... like a middle-eastern bank to my paypal account. (if this even is possible)

Comment: Ask Paypal to give you their bank's SWIFT code? Or to otherwise tell you what else you need? It's their business to know such things...

Comment: @keshlam I guess I'll. I thought there would be an easier way, like the swift code being public or something similar. I doubt every user asks paypal for swift code though

Comment: **Your** Paypal account number and IBAN? Where would you have gotten those? In which country is your Paypal account registered? From which country are you attempting to send funds? Is the bank account in your name? Paypal is very restrictive as to who can transfer funds into your Paypal account (yourself only, from an account in the same country, generally), and the details vary from country to country (in many countries, it is **not** possible to transfer money into a Paypal account by bank transfer, and AFAIK, in most if not all countries, you don't have a Paypal "account number" or IBAN).

Answer (score 3):

You can lookup SWIFT codes [here](http://www.swift.com/bsl/index.faces).  Based on the search I conducted on March 30, 2015, PayPay US's SWIFT is PPALUS66, and PayPal Europe's SWIFT is PPLXLULL.  Since they have two listed, it would be safe to contact PayPal directly and ask which SWIFT they would like to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with transferring money from my UK bank (HSBC) to my paypal... HSBC was asking for an IBAN code to complete the transaction. I couldn't find an IBAN code listed anywhere on my Paypal acct. What finally solved it for me was when I entered the last 4 digits of the Paypal account number, HSBC then threw up a message saying that payee was listed in my payees and to do a search for payees. (I had never manually entered my Paypal as a payee, but it was there in a huge list of companies already known and listed by HSBC.) Then all I had to do was put in the reference number Paypal had given and the amount. It was in my paypal account within minutes.

Hope this helps :)